# How to reference .NET MVC 5's Entity Framework ApplicationUser from a view without using a view model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using the default MVC 5 Individual Accounts template with Entity Framework to handle authentication. I have an `ApplicationUser` that inherits from `IdentityUser` with all the user's information. When the user's authenticated I can grab their `ApplicationUser` from the `UserManager` like so:

```
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
var AppUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

**How can I have that `ApplicationUser` available to all Views?**

I don't want to create a ViewModel, give it the `ApplicationUser`, and send that to the View. That seriously limits flexibility.

When using IPrincipal-based authentication I could use `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` as part of a static property on a class. How does this sort of thing work in the new Entity Framework `IdentityUser` world?

Comment: I thinks you should better to create your own view engine to achieve that http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=946

Comment: Really don't want to create my own view engine. Razor is just fine.

Comment: You're still using IPrincipal-based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I am not advocating use of the `ViewBag` but if you are really averse to using a ViewModel, you can add your ApplicationUser to the `ViewBag` like so:

```
ViewBag.User = AppUser;
```

Comment: I'd rather not use ViewBag. I'm trying to stop using that entirely.

Comment: @JordanRoher - but yet you'd rather completely break the separation of concerns by forcing your view to do data access?

Comment: Heh, I would. I do appreciate that I'm breaking best practices in a way, but I'd like to be able to access user data without a formal viewmodel. This isn't for an enterprise-quality app.

Comment: Well if you're not going to use a ViewModel and you're not going to use the ViewBag I have no other advice.